# Numerical solution for gradient(slope)

Tags: definite-integrals, physics, gradient-descent, numerical-calculus, slope

**Abstract**

I have the next equation to find a force, for my problem:

$$U=-\int \vec{m}\small{(x)}\times \vec{B}(x)dV$$
$$\vec{F}=-\nabla U$$

Considering 3-dimensional space with x,y,z coordinates, and, hence, $\vec{m}$ and $\vec{B}$ describe values at a point in the 3D space. Computing via C++. Each values described as:

```
class Vector3
{
public:
float x;
float y;
float z;
Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
{
   this->x=x;
   this->y=y;
   this->z=z;
}
};

Vector3 *m[1000];
Vector3 *B[1000];
Vector3 *F[1000];
```

Using: finding F vector literally at every point is impossible, so I will find values with some step. For example, considering some volume 1m*1m*1m, I will find values with step 100mm, so for that volume I need to calculate $\frac{1m}{100mm}* \frac{1m}{100mm}* \frac{1m}{100mm} =10^3=1000\space points$.

Fill array, I think should be the next way:

```
 int count=0;
 for(float x=0.0f;x<1.0f;x+=0.1f)
  for(float y=0.0f;y<1.0f;y+=0.1f) 
   for(float Z=0.0f;z<1.0f;z+=0.1f, count++)
      F[count]=new Vector3(...)\\here I calculate the formulas above
```

And I have particles, that move more smoothly, of course, not by 100mm steps, so I will just calculate which point is the nearest, or the average value of the nearest points in that point.

**Question**

How should I deal with it, if I have literally an array of $\vec{m}$ and $\vec{B}$ at every point, but not an analytical function, that describes distribution of that values?

As the output I need also array with $\vec{F}$ at every point.

**Thoughts**

I am bad at math, and have, probably wrong assumption. The formulas above wrote for finding **field** of forces. But in my case in need it to be “dotty”. Here is potential energy at a point.

$$\vec{m}\small{(x)}\times \vec{B}(x) = \frac{J}{T}*T=Joules=Potential\space Energy $$

But it doesn’t have any sense, because I need the **difference between two potentials**. So what if to calculate $\vec{F}(x)$(at a point) as 
$$\vec{F}(x)=\frac{U(x+k)-U(x)}{k}$$
Taking $k=step=100mm$?

Comment: Thought it is kinda trivial question...